# In oracle spool need to generate report with current date

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

[image]I am just trying to use the spool to generate a report with today date in csv.
When I run the following  ,its  asking me to enter date instead of appending dynamically.
My requirement is if I run the query it should generate file with today's date 
Example "Report_12-17-2019.csv" .  Kindly help me .

```
set serveroutput on size
SET LINESIZE 500
SET VERIFY OFF
SET FEEDBACK OFF
SET TERM OFF
set termout off
column tm new_value today
select to_char(sysdate,'DD_MM_YYYY') tm from dual;
set termout on
spool d:\temp\report&&__today.csv
exec audit_report();
spool off
```

Every time the last line only its prompting to enter the today.

Comment: worked for me.  also you have an extra dot.

Comment: A substitution variable can be ended with a dot and then the second dot becomes the separator between the file name and the file extension.  Like this: SPOOL  &&__SpoolPath.&&__SpoolFile._&&__DW_User..log

Comment: Thanks for answersing. But I used the above code still its asking me to enter the date. I am not sure what mistake I did . I am attaching the screen shot as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't appear to define `__today` anywhere. You only define `today`. Perhaps you meant to put an underscore before the `&&`?

Once that's fixed, you'll also need a second dot in the filename as the first one is used to terminate the substitution variable, otherwise

```
report&&today.csv
```

will become after substitution

```
report18_12_2019csv
```

Personally I prefer to use YYYY MM DD order in filenames as they sort more conveniently. Therefore:

```
column today new_value today
select to_char(sysdate,'YYYY_MM_DD') as today from dual;
spool d:\temp\report_&&today..csv
```